# Upload an image from JSON with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, cordova, backbone.js

I have an application created with PhoneGap and Backbone. I upload a file as JSon and my server receive data like this :

```
data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/...
```

I'm trying to write the file like this :

```
File.open("#{Rails.root}/public/images/#{self.id}.jpg", "w+") do |f|
  f.write(data)
end
```

It's not working and I don't know what to do. When I'm trying to open the file I have this message "Not a JPEG file: starts with 0x64 0x61".

Do you have a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was this :

```
f.write Base64.decode64(data).force_encoding('UTF-8')
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to decode the data first.

try:

```
File.open("#{Rails.root}/public/images/#{self.id}.jpg", "w+") do |f|
  decoded_data = Base64.decode64(data)
  image_data = StringIO.new(decoded_data)
  f.write(image_data)
end
```

Comment: Sorry but I replaced my code by yours and I've got the same error. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the following was the solution:
(Note the binary write option, when opening the file)!

```
File.open("#{Rails.root}/public/images/#{self.id}.jpg", "wb") do |f|
   f.write Base64.decode64(data)
end
```